# Bug in passing a variable in sql query

Tags: python, sql, mysql, database

I was trying to pass a variable in sql query using python. But Some other variable is getting passed in the query.

```
PostNewUniqueVal = 0
                        BETA__ = True
                        while BETA__:
                            RandNumm = random.randrange(100000000000,99999999999999)
                            if RandNumm in AllPostID:
                                continue
                            else:
                                PostNewUniqueVal = RandNumm
                                BETA__ = False

                        AddPost_connection2 = mysql.connector.connect(host=HOSTNAME,user=USER,password=PASSWD,database=DB)
                        AddPost_cursor2 = AddPost_connection2.cursor()

                        PostContent = PostText_entry.get("0.0", "end")
                        PostingUserID = USER_DET['USER_ID']
                        PostSno = ALPHA2__[-1]+1
                        PostIDNew = PostNewUniqueVal

                        AddPost_cursor2.execute(f'INSERT INTO `posts`(`sno`, `user_id`, `post_id`, `post_content`) VALUES ({PostSno},{PostingUserID},{PostIDNew},"{PostContent}")')

                        AddPost_connection2.commit()
                        AddPost_connection2.close()
                        AddPost_frame.destroy()
```

For example: If values of PostNewUniqueVal is 2, in the query 7 is passed

Comment: Never use string concatenation or formatting to construct your query if you don't want to be a victim of SQL injection. That's what's the second parameter of `execute` is for.

Comment: @Matthias - Good suggestion. What should they use instead?

Comment: @Abbilaash, if you print(PostIDNew) after assignment, is the value what you expect?

Comment: @Captain Caveman 
 If I print(PostIDNew) the values is correct. But if I try to print the query after placing the variable, some other number is passed. I checked the whole code for similar variable names. But ended up with a negative result.

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains the following, with signposting to explain what it does:

```
# Initialize a variable to store a new unique value for a post ID
PostNewUniqueVal = 0 

# Set a flag to indicate that the loop should continue running
BETA__ = True

# Keep generating random numbers until a unique one is found
while BETA__:
    # Generate a random number between 100000000000 and 99999999999999
    RandNumm = random.randrange(100000000000,99999999999999)
    
    # Check if the generated number is already in the list of all post IDs
    if RandNumm in AllPostID:
        # If it is, continue generating new numbers
        continue
    else:
        # If it is not, set the new unique value for the post ID and exit the loop
        PostNewUniqueVal = RandNumm
        BETA__ = False

# Set the new post ID to the unique value that was found
PostIDNew = PostNewUniqueVal
```

So, the code generates **a new unique post ID** by generating random numbers until one is found that is not already in the list of all post IDs. The new post ID is then set to this unique value.

i.e. you could initialize with a value of 2, but get 7 inserted into SQL query because **PostIDNew is established by random number**.

---

To avoid SQL injection and pass the correct parameters, use parameterized queries. e.g.

```
AddPost_cursor2.execute('INSERT INTO `posts`(`sno`, `user_id`, `post_id`, `post_content`) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)', (PostSno, PostingUserID, PostIDNew, PostContent))
```

This passes the values to the execute method which will handle escaping and quoting of the values to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: This too doesn't work. Same bug is displayed.

Comment: A new beginning to my answer has been added. I think the problem is that your code does something you didn't expect.

Comment: Exactly. I dont know where the values gets changed.

Comment: I provided you a guide to how it gets changed: there is a random number generated, it is then passed into **PostNewUniqueVal** in this line `PostNewUniqueVal = RandNumm`  THEN that variable's value is passed into **PostIDNew** via this line `PostIDNew = PostNewUniqueVal` so when you get to the insert `VALUES ({PostSno},{PostingUserID},{` **PostIDNew**  that parameter is the result of a random number. This is not accidental, it is a deliberate act by the person who wrote the code.